# CSS classes from styled-components don't being deleted after become unused using server side rendering

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, server-side-rendering, styled-components

Every time since the server started, new CSS classes append into the end of `<style data-styled-components="...">...</style>` on render. But they don't being deleted after page reload when new classes are generated (however old classes become useless).

I suppose this is because all classes stay in memory.
Is there a way to avoid this?

Here is the image that is show it stacked too much:

[image: Because it has been stacked too much.]

I tried to change version of styled-components package, to configure `babel-plugin-styled-components`/`typescript-plugin-styled-components`, but nothing helped me.